# How to get an input from the user and execute the input as a python code(sql) in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I searched for this but problem a lot but still couldn't figure it out yet.
I will try to keep it simple.

I have this code , which is basically a Text box and submit button , the user will write a python code in the Text box ( the code is to alter or change a certain table or database in sqlite3) and after hitting submit the code the user wrote should be executed.

example of a code the user will write in the Text box :

```
insert into employee(id,first_name,last_name,password)
values (456,'test','tesst','testpass')
```

I will show you the code I have so far :

```
        admin_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        admin_window.title('Admin Window')
        admin_window.geometry("450x450")
        sql_commands = tk.Text(admin_window)
        sql_commands.place(height=350, width=350,relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        submit_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text=' Submit ', command=submit_click)
        submit_button.place(anchor='center',y=200,relx=0.5, rely=0.5,)
```

as you can see there is a Text box ( the text box is in a new window not in the root )

when the user press submit this is how I can get the input from him:

```
input = sql_commands.get("1.0",'end')
```

it return the input correctly, but the type is weird , the type is bunch of number then str at the end.

How can I take the input to execute it and treat it like a code? is this even a proper way do it ?

Comment: use the function `exec(YOUR_TEXT_CODE_HERE)` to execute the text that you obtained as code. For more info refer to [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec)

Comment: @AST How will python execute SQL code ?

Comment: @Cloud Cool Well I agree to you but I have assumed that they will add this to a larger string that contains the rest of the code, the OP asked "How can I take the input to execute it and treat it like a code?" they didn't tell would be executing it directly.

Comment: What the OP should do is `import sqlite` and use it to create a cursor and then execute statements for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import tkinter as tk


def submit_click():
    exec(sql_commands.get("1.0", 'end'))


root = tk.Tk()

admin_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
admin_window.title('Admin Window')
admin_window.geometry("450x450")
sql_commands = tk.Text(admin_window)
sql_commands.place(height=350, width=350, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
submit_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text=' Submit ', command=submit_click)
submit_button.place(anchor='center', y=200, relx=0.5, rely=0.5,)

root.mainloop()
```

The type seems normal on my end, just a string. You shouldn't use 'input' however as that is a built-in function in python.

The exec() function is also a built-in, and it executes a string as python code. Short guide on exec [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/#:%7E:text=exec()%20function%20is%20used,code%2C%20it%20is%20simply%20executed.)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAl-Sallum I don't understand, how will the user execute SQL commands with `exec()`? And also the user can `import os` and then even shutdown the pc from there within.

Comment: He wants to execute python code given by the user, and I've never used sql but I assume it's not too hard to interact with a database using python code

Comment: As for the import os being able to shutdown the computer, yes this is true but if you want the user to be able to execute python code then I'm not sure how you can avoid that

Comment: The user has mentioned that _"the code is to alter or change a certain table or database in sqlite3"_. And it is not "hard" to execute sql code from python.